# How do I set a session cookie to secure and use CSRF tokens?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express application where I am trying to set the session cookie to secure.  So far I have tried the code below:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
sessionOptions = definitions.REDIS;
sessionOptions.ttl = definitions.session.expiration;
app.use(express.session({
  secret: definitions.session.secret,
  cookie: {                 <---------------------------- Added this
    secure: true
  },
  store: new RedisStore(sessionOptions)
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.csrf());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.token = req.session._csrf;
  return next();
});
```

But now when I try to log in the CSRF token does not validate and I get a forbidden error.  How can I make the session cookie secure AND use a CSRF token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I use. I don't think you need the `return` before `next()`, but I'm not sure if that's your issue.

```
app
.set('view engine', 'jade')
.set('views', __dirname + '/../views')
.set('json spaces', 2)
.use(express.compress())
.use(express.cookieParser('our secret'))
.use(express.session({
  store: new RedisStore({
    port: config.redisPort,
    host: config.redisHost,
    db: config.redisDatabase,
    pass: config.redisPassword
  }),
  proxy: true,
  cookie: { httpOnly: true, secure: true }
}))
.use(express.bodyParser())
.use(express.methodOverride())
.use(express.csrf())
.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken());
  res.locals.csrftoken = req.csrfToken();
  next();
})
.use(everyauth.middleware());
```

The `proxy: true` is necessary for Heroku. Note that `req.session._csrf` has been obsoleted in the latest version of Express.